# Generating all possible subsets of a given QuerySet in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is just an example, but given the following model:

```
class Foo(models.model):
    bar = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.bar)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.bar)
```

And the following `QuerySet` object:

```
foobar = Foo.objects.filter(bar__lt=20).distinct()
```

(meaning, a set of unique `Foo` models with `bar <= 20`), how can I generate all possible subsets of `foobar`? Ideally, I'd like to further limit the subsets so that, for each subset `x` of `foobar`, the sum of all `f.bar` in `x` (where `f` is a model of type `Foo`) is between some maximum and minimum value.

So, for example, given the following instance of `foobar`:

```
>> print foobar
[<Foo: 5>, <Foo: 10>, <Foo: 15>]
```

And `min=5`, `max=25`, I'd like to build an object (preferably a `QuerySet`, but possibly a list) that looks like this:

```
[[<Foo: 5>], [<Foo: 10>], [<Foo: 15>], [<Foo: 5>, <Foo: 10>],
 [<Foo: 5>, <Foo: 15>], [<Foo: 10>, <Foo: 15>]]
```

I've experimented with `itertools` but it doesn't seem particularly well-suited to my needs.

I *think* this could be accomplished with a complex `QuerySet` but I'm not sure how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the [powerset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of `foobar` (as a list)

```
from itertools import combinations
[j for i in range(len(foobar)+1) for j in combinations(foobar,i)]
```

Adding a filter for the minval and maxval gives:

```
from itertools import combinations
[j for i in range(len(foobar)+1) for j in combinations(foobar,i)
 if minval <= sum(f.bar for f in j) <= maxval]
```

Lets create a class and try it out

```
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, bar):
...         self.bar=bar
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return  "<Foo: %s>"%self.bar
... 
>>> foobar=[Foo(5),Foo(10),Foo(15)]
>>> minval=5
>>> maxval=25
>>> [j for i in range(len(foobar)+1) for j in combinations(foobar,i) 
     if minval <= sum(f.bar for f in j) <= maxval]
[(<Foo: 5>,), (<Foo: 10>,), (<Foo: 15>,), (<Foo: 5>, <Foo: 10>), (<Foo: 5>, <Foo: 15>), (<Foo: 10>, <Foo: 15>)]
```

If you need lists rather than tuples it's trivial to add that in too

```
>>> [list(j) for i in range(len(foobar)+1) for j in combinations(foobar,i) if minval <= sum(f.bar for f in j) <= maxval ]
[[<Foo: 5>], [<Foo: 10>], [<Foo: 15>], [<Foo: 5>, <Foo: 10>], [<Foo: 5>, <Foo: 15>], [<Foo: 10>, <Foo: 15>]]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
S = [list(itertools.combinations(foobar,i)) for i in xrange(1, len(foobar))]
```

It produces non-flat list. You can flatten it by:

```
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(S))
```